# Mist 0.7.3: how long does it take to sync and how much data do I need to download?

Tags: mist, blockchain, synchronization, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I just installed Mist 0.7.3 and would like to know how long does it usually take and how much data does it download as of today. What other alternatives are there to Mist if I dont want to download the entire blockchain.

Answer (score 5):

You can expect roughly around 9-10 GB of data.  How long it takes can depend on your network connection. I would say at least several hours to fully synch.

If you want to use something other than Mist, you can use goethereum aka `geth` standalone and add the `--fast` flag to synch much faster (note Mist includes geth).  Alternatively you could use `parity` another ethereum client.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the first time you run Mist it will sync with the --fast flag enabled. You will be downloading and verifing only the 1.5 million block headers of Ethereum blockchain. It should take you around 4 GB of bandwidth and less than an hour on a modern laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I just re-synced using `geth --fast` on my mid-2012 Macbook Pro w/ SSD on Time Warner basic internet package in LA.

I started at 10:47PM PST. It completed 1.5m blocks at 1:19am PST. So expect ~2.5hrs, at least.

The chaindata folder is now 1.95GB, though from here on out it'll grow pretty rapidly.

I had been syncing since November previously and my chaindata folder was 16gb. Highly recommend you do a `geth removedb` and `geth -fast` every few months or so.

Comment: where is the folder that stores this chain data?

Comment: It's in the same folder as your keystore folder. So you can go in mist to account backup accounts and go up one level and you should see the chaindata folder.